# Selecting tweets based on searchwords in R

Tags: r, text, twitter, spatial

For my thesis I am working with tweets. I am trying to select only the tweets that contain certain words. Since I am analysing the tweets geographically I have them as a SpatialPointDataFrame (SPDF). As a result I want to see on a map where the tweets about these words come from so I want to select them from the SPDF, as a new SPDF.

I figured this should be easy with the package tm (Text Mining) or with general functions like scan. But unfortunately I find it difficult to find a function that allows me to scan the tweets for a certain word. My next step would be to work around it, converting the tweets in the SPDF to a textfile, selecting the tweets using one of the functions I have been trying with the SPDF, and then link them back to the SPDF to make them spatial again.

In the programming language R someone has told me to not start making functions since most functions you will try to make already exist. So before I am breaking my brain on this situation I am posting it here hoping someone has the result at hand.

So I have a SPDF with a lot of tweets. I want to select all tweets that contain a certain word. And that's it! It still sounds so easy to me and I feel like I am just not getting the right line of thought at the moment.

Please help!

EDIT!!!!!

all_tweets_containing_word_test_are_true <- grepl('test', spatialpointdataframe$twt_txt)

??? Select all true numbers of spatialpointdataframe ???

Comment: Not familiar with SPDF, but can't you use grepl to subset it like a normal data.frame?

Comment: Thank you! I am very close now :) adjusting my original question, but should be able to figure it out tomorrow when I am fresh again.

Comment: some code & data structures would help. First impression aligns with [@JeremyS](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3189041/jeremys)'s in that you might want to start with just a regular data frame, do some `tm` analyses and then try to integrate geographical information.

Comment: Well I suspect there is not much code to it. One line that selects all the numbers that are TRUE. With that data I should be able to select out of the original SPDF all numbers that are TRUE after using grepl. Maybe by using match or something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a regular data frame you use grepl like this:

```
Sub.DF <- DF[grepl('test', DF$twt_txt),]
```

As long as an SPDF works like that then this should be what you want. You won't even need to make the Sub.DF object if you just want to plot it. If you use ggplot2 or ggmap or something then just use `data=DF[grepl('test', DF$twt_txt),]`